# Does $e^{1/t}$ have a Laplace Transform?

Tags: laplace-transform

I'm having a little trouble understanding why some functions have a Laplace transformation and others don't.

The definition I was given in class last week was "Given a suitable function $F(t)$ the Laplace transform, written $f(s)$ is defined by

$$f(s)=\int_0^{\infty} F(t)\,e^{-st} dt$$

We were told some conditions for "suitability", like "All polynomial functions and exponential functions (of the type $e^{kt}$, $k$=constant) are suitable, as well as all bounded functions". And that, "Excluded functions are those that have singularities such as $\ln(t)$ and $1/(t-1)$, and functions with a growth rate more rapid than the standard exponential such as $e^{t^2}$."

But these definitions seem a bit loose to me, and now I've encountered the following problem: "Does $e^{t^{-1}}$ have a Laplace Transform, if so then what is it, and if not then why not?"

I don't think it does, because it's discontinuous at $t=0$ and the growth-rate isn't like a "standard" exponential growth-rate... But I'm honestly not sure now.

(P.S. Apologies for the equations not being all pretty and such, I haven't worked out how to do that yet)

Comment: A possible simple definition of 'suitability' is that $F$ is suitable if there exists $c$ such that $F(t)e^{-ct}$ is integrable on $[0, \infty)$. This guarantees that $f(s)$ exists for $s \geq c$ (though it may also be defined on a larger set). This encompasses any suitable examples you mentioned. Now it is not hard to prove that there is no such $c$ for $F(t) = e^{1/t}$. A hint is that it is enough to look at the integral over $[0, 1]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason, your instructor doesn't seem to be giving the obvious definition, which is that a function has a Laplace transform iff the corresponding integral which defines the transform exists (and is not infinity, since some definitions of integral accept infinity as a value).  Perhaps that is because there are different definitions of integrals (e.g., Riemann, Lebesgue, "improper", "principal value").

What you want to know is whether
$$f(s)=\int_0^{\infty} e^{1/t}\,e^{-st} dt$$
exists and for what $s$.  For domain of integration $[1,\infty)$ it's no sweat: for $t\ge 1$, $e^{1/t}\le e$, so the integral exists for $s>0$ because $\int_1^\infty e^{-st}\,dt$ does.  For $[0,1]$, however, $e^{-st}\ge e^{-s}$, and so $f(s)\ge e^{-s}\int_a^1 e^{1/t}\,dt$ for all $0<a<1$.  The latter quantity becomes infinitely large as we let $a$ go to zero, since $e^{1/t}\ge 1/t$ and $\int_0^1 dt/t$ diverges.  Because of this, $e^{1/t}$, I'd say, lacks a Laplace transform.

Caveat:  There may be some way I'm unaware of to give the Laplace transform of $e^{1/t}$ a meaning.

Answer (score 7):

Short answer, no.  There is a nonintegrable singularity at $t=0$.

Longer, much more subtle answer...we can define a LT of this function, just not in the usual way.  Rather, it is an analytical continuation of another, seemingly unrelated result.  Let me explain a bit.

We begin with the following known result which I will not derive here:

$$\int_0^{\infty} dt \, e^{-1/t} e^{-s t} = \frac{2 K_1 \left ( 2 \sqrt{s} \right )}{\sqrt{s}} $$

where $K_1$ the modified Bessel function of the second kind of first order.  We may express this as an inverse LT:

$$\frac1{i 2 \pi} \int_{c-i \infty}^{c+i \infty} ds \, \frac{2 K_1 \left ( 2 \sqrt{s} \right )}{\sqrt{s}} e^{s t} = e^{-1/t} $$

Now, throwing caution to the wind, we replace $t \mapsto -t$:

$$e^{1/t} = \frac1{i 2 \pi} \int_{c-i \infty}^{c+i \infty} ds \, \frac{2 K_1 \left ( 2 \sqrt{s} \right )}{\sqrt{s}} e^{-s t}$$

To get this to be a proper-looking ILT, replace $s \mapsto -s$:

$$\begin{align}e^{1/t} &= \frac1{i 2 \pi} \int_{-c-i \infty}^{-c+i \infty} ds \, \left [i \frac{2 K_1 \left ( i 2 \sqrt{s} \right )}{\sqrt{s}}\right ] e^{s t} \\ &= \frac1{i 2 \pi} \int_{-c-i \infty}^{-c+i \infty} ds \, \left [-\frac{\pi Y_1 \left ( 2 \sqrt{s} \right )}{\sqrt{s}} - i \frac{\pi J_1 \left ( 2 \sqrt{s} \right )}{\sqrt{s}}\right ] e^{s t}\end{align}$$

where $Y_1$ and $J_1$ are, respectively, the Bessel functions of the second and first kind of first order.  One more simplification: the $J_1$ term is analytic in the complex plane to the left of the line of integration and as such contributes nothing to this integral.  Thus, we can say that

$$e^{1/t} = \frac1{i 2 \pi} \int_{-c-i \infty}^{-c+i \infty} ds \, \left [-\frac{\pi Y_1 \left ( 2 \sqrt{s} \right )}{\sqrt{s}} \right ] e^{s t} $$

Now, we haven't really done anything radical yet.  We actually still need to close the contour to the right rather than the left in order to capture the singularity at $s=0$.  (We assumed that $c \gt 0$.)  However, we can for the sake of a definition of a true inverse map $c \mapsto -c$ so that we define the ILT of $e^{1/t}$ for $t \gt 0$ (even though, again, it really doesn't make sense from the original definition).

In this sense, we can define the LT of $e^{1/t}$ as

$$\mathcal{L}\left [e^{1/t} \right ] = -\frac{\pi Y_1 \left ( 2 \sqrt{s} \right )}{\sqrt{s}}$$

even though the integral is not defined.

**ADDENDUM**

Just for laughs, if you have Mathematica, type in `LaplaceTransform[Exp[1/t], t, s]` and it returns the above result.  Trying to evaluate the original integral of course results in a "Divergent integral" message.

Comment: Just something that came into my mind. Is it possible to set up a Taylor Series for the given function? (Obviously not centered at zero) and determine term by term Laplace transform of the  resulting $n$ polynomial terms? In terms of approximating the "true" answer, is this approach legitimate?

Comment: @imranfat: I don't see how to pull that off at first glance.  Maybe you have some idea?

Comment: I wouldn't know in this particular case either. The thought that came into my mind was more of general nature. If a function has a Taylor expansion, would the LT of a bunch of these polynomial terms be a valid approximation of the LT of the given function, if the latter one is difficult to derive?

Comment: @RonGordon in regards to your addendum I ran the command in mathematica 12.3 and it didn't give an output(it spat the same command back out lol) so idk

Comment: @Max0815 This is even more peculiar. As you said, using Mathematica 14.0 also just spits out the command, however, copying in the command to WolframAlpha gives out the result by RonGordon. It's the first time Wolfram could do something Mathematica didn't, which is strange since WA is just a light version of Mathematica...